# How can i sum rows when a certain column value are equal from another table and insert them to a third table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to sum rows when a column are equal then copy them to another table when column = column.

better to write down my tables then u guys can understand it.

1. Table1
   +------+------+------+
   |  ID  | Col1 | Col2 |
   +------+------+------+
   | 1658 |   86 |  117 |
   | 1665 |   65 |   14 |
   | 1667 |   66 |   72 |
   | 1669 |   78 |   12 |
   +------+------+------+
2. Table2
   +--------+------+------+
   | AreaID |  ID  | Col1 |
   +--------+------+------+
   |      1 | 1658 | bla  |
   |      1 | 1665 | bla  |
   |      2 | 1667 | bla  |
   |      2 | 1669 | bla  |
   +--------+------+------+
3. Table3
   +--------+------+------+
   | AreaID | Col1 | Col2 |
   +--------+------+------+
   |      1 |    0 |    0 |
   |      2 |    0 |    0 |
   +--------+------+------+

Well what i want to do is calculating the SUM of Col1 and Col2 From Table1 when ID.Table1 = ID.Table2 and AreaID.Table2 are equal !, Then UPDATE Table3 with the sum of rows.
It seems kinda hard but it's so important for me.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks to anyone that does help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `Join` to an `Inner Select` in your `Update` statement while aggregating your columns with `Sum`.  If I understood your column structure and question correctly, this should be what you need:

```
Update  T3
Set     Col1 = U.Col1Total,
        Col2 = U.Col2Total
From    Table3 T3
Join
(
    Select  T2.AreaID,
            Sum(T1.Col1) Col1Total,
            Sum(T1.Col2) Col2Total
    From    Table1 T1
    Join    Table2 T2   On  T1.Id = T2.Id
    Group By T2.AreaId
) U On U.AreaId = T3.AreaId
```

Comment: That's awesome^^ ,, working like a charm!
also it's easy to understand! thanks alot